# How can I optimize the multi-threading in my WINAPI function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety

There isn't any major problems, per se, however, somepeople told me that this program wasn't very reliable, that the code was burning extra cycles on the thread for nothing and that I shouldn't use the C++ standard I/O stream for what I'm trying to do.

For anyone wondering, the program kicks out the user if he doesn't enter an option in the given amount of time which is 5s in this case, if he does give an answer then the program continues running.

This is the program in question:

```
#include <windows.h>

namespace jsw {
    namespace threading {
        class auto_event {
        public:
            auto_event() : _event(CreateEvent(0, false, false, 0)) {}

            BOOL wait(DWORD timeout = 1) const
            {
                return WaitForSingleObject(_event, timeout) == WAIT_OBJECT_0;
            }

            BOOL set() { return SetEvent(_event); }
            BOOL reset_event() { return ResetEvent(_event); }
        private:
            HANDLE _event;
        };

        class thread {
        public:
            static thread start(
                LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE fn, LPVOID args = 0,
                DWORD state = 0, DWORD timeout = 20000)
            {
                return thread(CreateThread(0, 0, fn, args, state, 0), timeout);
            }

            static void sleep(DWORD milliseconds) { Sleep(milliseconds); }
            static void exit(DWORD exitCode) { ExitThread(exitCode); }
        public:
            thread(HANDLE thread, DWORD timeout) : _thread(thread), _timeout(timeout) {}
            ~thread() { CloseHandle(_thread); }

            DWORD exit_code() const
            {
                DWORD exitCode = NO_ERROR;

                GetExitCodeThread(_thread, &exitCode);

                return exitCode;
            }

            HANDLE handle() const { return _thread; }
            BOOL is_alive() const { return exit_code() == STILL_ACTIVE; }
            DWORD join() { return WaitForSingleObject(_thread, _timeout); }
            DWORD suspend() { return SuspendThread(_thread); }
            DWORD resume() { return ResumeThread(_thread); }
            BOOL abort(DWORD exitCode) { return TerminateThread(_thread, exitCode); }
        private:
            HANDLE _thread;
            DWORD _timeout;
        };
    }
}

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

DWORD WINAPI get_option(LPVOID args)
{
    using namespace jsw::threading;

    int* option = (int*)((LPVOID*)args)[0];
    auto_event* e = (auto_event*)((LPVOID*)args)[1];

    std::cout << "Option: ";
    std::cin >> *option;
    e->set();

    return NO_ERROR;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace jsw::threading;

    int option{};
    auto_event e;
    LPVOID args[2] = { &option, &e };

    while (true)
    {
        thread worker = thread::start(get_option, args);

        if (e.wait(5000)) {
            system("cls");
            switch (option) {
            case 1:
                std::cout << "Option 1" << std::endl;
                break;
            case 2:
                std::cout << "Option 2" << std::endl;
                break;
            case 3: // Exit
                break;
            default: std::cout << "Option not valid!" << std::endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            worker.abort(NO_ERROR);
            std::cout << "***PROGRAM END***\n";
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried searching for a way to make the WINAPI function work without the C++ I/O stream, as well as optimizing the thread, however, I wasn't able to find a satisfying answer that was clear and simple enough for what I'm trying to achieve.

If possible can someone please provide a clear explanation on the way I can optimize this program?

Comment: whats the purpose of the code? Without that info any code is just "burning cycles".

Comment: `auto_event` probably needs a destructor, and for copy constructors and assignment to be disabled

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I edited it to specify the purpose of the program.

Comment: Copy constructor is a technical term that can be searched. You can't learn c++ without being able to research.

Comment: perhaps not immediately clear, but this is very related, also to what Mooi suggested https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminatethread): `TerminateThread` is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases.  Closing `cin` in the main thread might be a viable alternative.

Comment: (When the timeout expires, I mean)

Comment: @PaulSanders Should I use  `THREAD_TERMINATE` to replace `TerminateThread`?

Comment: You need to get the thread to return from `std::cin >> *option;`.  As I say, try closing `cin` in the main thread (after which you won't be able to use it, of course).  To answer your actual question, you have no 'busy loop', so that's all fine.

Comment: @PaulSanders Could you please provide an example on returning the thread from `cin`? I am new to C++ so I don't understand everything but I appreciate your help nonetheless. Last thought, the abort function closes `cin` (once the timer is done) since you can't use it after.

Comment: If you make `abort` call `std::cin.close()`, then `std::cin >> *option;` should return and `std::cin.is_open()` should subsequently return `false`.  Is that enough info for you to give it a go?

Comment: @RexyCode What `TerminateThread` does (other than end the thread) is potentially corrupt the state of your process.   After calling `TerminateThread` (or any other API the forcefully terminates a thread) the program is always in potential Undefined Behaviour land.

Comment: The program always owns only one thread and terminates when the thread runs out. For an example using threads, see [Creating Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-threads).

Comment: [Windows started picking up the really big pieces of TerminateThread garbage on the sidewalk, but it’s still garbage on the sidewalk](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811). As I noted previously, the way to move forward is to stop using multiple threads. Windows' I/O is asynchronous by default. You just need to create a pipe over STDIN and register a completion callback. All that's left is putting the calling thread into an alertable state (e.g. [`SleepEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleepex)).

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs, I will try my best to learn more about those different subjects and apply them in my program, if anyone as another solution for the optimization of my program I will be happy to read it.

Comment: @IInspectable Do you have a website that explains how to go about creating a pipe over STDIN and registering a completion callback? Probably should specify I only have 6 months of experience in C++ so all of those concepts are kinda hard to grasp but I will try my best.